# HttpClient doesn't works in IOs app builded in VS with Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I try to make an awaitable request in my PCL/Android/iOs project. Function for request is in PCL

```
public class DataService
{
    private static string _requestUri = "https://requesturi.com/";
    public static async Task<LocalizationData> GetLocalization(string code)
    {
        string queryString = _requestUri + "get_localization.php" + "?code=" + code;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);
        dynamic data = null;
        if (response != null)
        {
            string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            if (data["status"] == "success")
            {
                List<string> aliases = new List<string>();
                List<string> translations = new List<string>();
                foreach (var localization in data["localizations"])
                {
                    aliases.Add((string)localization["alias"]);
                    translations.Add((string)localization["translation"]);
                }
                LocalizationData localizationData = new LocalizationData(code, aliases.ToArray(), translations.ToArray());
                return localizationData;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both in Android and iOS I call this function with

`localizationData = await DataService.GetLocalization(langCode);`

In Android it works without problems both on simulator and on real device.
But when I try run it in iOS, on simulator it works fine, on real device app crash on

`var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);`

Is it something about permissions? Or something else?
Can anybody help me with this problem?

**UPDATED**

There are exception for **client.GetAsync(queryString)** I get in app on real device:
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object"

Comment: Try to connect to a HTTP instead of HTTPS and check whether there is also having same errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the thread in [Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36713/issue-with-microsoft-http-net-library-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-objec) this is issue with Reference. Seems like httpClient instance was created in mono memory but not in iOS memory, due to a difference between an iOS device(AOT) and simulator(JIT) build nature.

Try :

> 1) Go to References of ios Project
>
> 2) Edit References
>
> 3) Check 'System.Net.Http'

In general - use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) - it provides wrappers for native networking API, it is secure and faster then default .Net HttpClient.

Comment: As I said in my question - Android part works without problem. Problem appears only when I run app on iOs real device.

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus have to find the solution?. Please guide me having same issue.